# Access Play Scala variable in AngularJS $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scala, playframework-2.0

I have tried a number of approaches suggested on StackOverflow, and have still not been able to access a Play Scala variable in my Javascript $scope. The initializing line in an HTML file reads:

```
@(playVariable: String)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request[Any])
```

I can access this value **between** HTML tags as on-screen text by doing something like:

```
<h2>Play value: @playVariable</h2>
```

However, I don't know how to set this variable to a `$scope` value ... Also, I don't believe that the Play `@` is valid within HTML tags, so `event.currentTarget.scalaVal` ends up `undefined` in `$scope.angularFunction`:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="angularFunction(parameter);" scalaVal=@playVariable>Click!</button>
```

I need to access `@playVariable` in `$scope.angularFunction` to pass into a backend HTTP call... How may I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried to surround the variable with quotes? So it looks like this: `scalaVal="@playVariable"`

Answer (score 0):

The approach we take is to set some global variables, on window, when generating the HTML from Play, then accessing the global variables from the Angular code. Yeah, global is generally bad, but sometimes it's easier. Our Angular code is a Single Page App, and we don't want to modify the templates on the Play side, which it looks like what you are trying to do.

If you don't want to do that and instead want to modify your Angular template on the Play side before serving them up, you could try passing your play variable inside your function call, something like:

```
ng-click=angularFunction(parameter, @playVariable)"
```